# Wrong version number in packages folder when using "nuget.exe restore solution"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package-restore

On some host, when using `nuget.exe restore solution.sln`
to force package restoration before build, I observe that command does not behave in identicall way compare to Nuget visual plugin.

On some host the command version append the build number (default value 0) to the version number,
causing the path in package folder to contain that build number.

So for example instead of having:

```
/packages/my_package.1.57.0/...
```

I have instead :

```
/packages/my_package.1.57.0.0/...
```

In the end it cause the build to fail, because internally,
target that are stored inside the .vcxproj are looking for the first path that do not contain the build number.
I don't know if it's relevant to the observered behavior, but those package are native C++ package build using [CoApp](http://coapp.org/index.html)

If instead of using nuget.exe on the same host, I am using the package manager restore functionnality from visual 2013, it works wells, and package are properly copied with path that don't include the build number.
And then build is ok.

As `nuget.exe` work on some host and not on some other, I am suspecting either a different version of a component or a different default setting.

For the component I have checked:

nuget version:  2.8.50926.602

visual 2013 version: 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

And they are identical on both host that work and that don't.
So what's left ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it end up to the following simple scenario (unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue):

- package in trouble where homemade package of boost library.
- some of these package may have been available with the same name, but
  different content and version numbering on nuget.org

On a workstation having the issue I was able to solve it by:

- disabling nuget.org from the list of repos
- and most importantly => CLEARING the nuget cache !

Even if I was not able to reproduce : I am quite confident about this scenario, because when looking inside the package I saw that the content was different from the one I had built. So this package have been downloaded from elsewhere.